# sort list of dataframes in python by highest value in shared column

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to sort a list of pandas dataframes by the highest value of one of the columns in the dataframes (the columns are shared by the dataframes)?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  We love questions!  So don't be discouraged by the downvote.  However, those of us who answer questions have expectations on the questions that get asked.  We've even put together other posts to describe [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  And what [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) means.  I suggest you read those two articles and edit your question accordingly.  In the long run, you'll be glad that you did.  It really will help you get your questions answered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {"id":[1,2,3],"age":[10,20,60]}
dict2 = {"id":[4,5,6],"age":[10,20,40]}

df1 = DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
df2 = DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)

dflist = [df1,df2]


sorteddflist= sorted(dflist,key=lambda x:x["age"].max(axis=0))
for i in sorteddflist:
    print(i)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work.
https://i.imgur.com/B4JcDdE.png